# django forms - remove "submit" button

Tags: django, forms, submit

I have a simple form that enables selecting an option (radio button). Upon selection the form automatically submits itself (using the `onchange` attribute):

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
      choices=forms.ChoiceField( widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'onchange': 'this.form.submit();'}), choices=[(k,k) for k in options],label="choose one")
```

This is great, only problem is I still have the "submit" button at the bottom of the form when it's rendered. Is it possible, without creating a template, to somehow make the form render without a submit button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Django doc](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template):

> The form only outputs its own fields;
>   it is up to you to provide the
>   surrounding  tags and the submit
>   button.

It means that you probably have the submit button in you template - remove it if you don't need it.